# VritualBox ошибка при запуске: Kernel driver not installed

Tags: macos, virtualbox

[image: Фото]

В чем проблема, пытаюсь запустить VirtualBox на Mac OS, выдает ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Откройте: **System Settings** ⇒ **Security and Privacy** ⇒ **General**. Там вы найдете заблокированное ПО от Oracle. Нужно разрешить к нему доступ, чтобы оно смогло работать. Галочка `allow Oracle` присутствует в списке только первые 30 минут после возникновения ошибки инсталляции.

См. [Apple technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2459/_index.html).

---

См. [Installation of Virtual Box on Mac OS — Kernel Driver Not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49613092/11141611).

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в настройки безопасности и разрешите загрузку стороннего ПО, там будет специальный пункт для этого.

Если же его нет на основной вкладке, то необходимо полностью удалить `VirtualBox` и установить его снова, повторив первый пункт. Таким образом все необходимые компоненты будут установлены и ошибка должна будет пропасть.